# Sync Option Set Value From XDB to CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

I am using Dynamics Connector to sync data between Sitecore and CRM.

I need to update a dropdown field with selected value in CRM from Sitecore. Any suggestions on how this can be mapped ?

http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DynamicsCrmConnect/v2.0.1/adding-custom-data/sitecore-to-dynamics/index.html

The documentation does not have details of custom mapping.

Thanks,
Samridhi

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining custom facet `Graduate Year` drop down. Please follow below steps:

**Specify how to read from the Dynamics contact**

- Navigate to this location Navigate to this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Data Access/Value Accessor`
- Add item `GraduateYear on Dynamics Contact` using template `Entity Attribute Value Accessor`
- Set the following field values

> **Attribute Name**: CRM Field Name
>
> **Value Type**: Option Set Value (If dropdown otherwise blank for single line)

**Specify how to write to the Contact facet**

- Navigate to this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/xConnect`
- Add the following item.

> **Template** : xConnect Entity Facet Value Accessor Set
>
> **Item Name**: xConnect Contact Custom Information Facet

- Select the new item.
- Add the following item.

> **Template** : xConnect Entity Facet Property Value Accessor
>
> **Item Name**: Graduate Year on xConnect Graduate Year

- Set the following field values:

> Facet Property: Collection Models > Custom Models > YourCustomModel > Facets > Contact > FacetKey > GraduateYear

- Save the item.

**Drop Down Settings**

- Navigate to this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Tenant Settings/Common/Code Definition Sets`
- Add the following item.

> **Template** : Code Definition Set
>
> **Item Name**: Dynamics Graduate Year Code

- Select the new item
- Add the following item.

> **Template** : Code Definition
>
> **Item Name**: 2019

- Set the following field values:

> **Value**: Similar which is assign in CRM

- Navigate to this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Data Access/Value Readers/Providers/Dynamics`
- Add the following item.

> **Template** : Description to Code Value Reader
>
> **Item Name**: Dynamics Graduate Year Description to Code Reader

- Set the following field values:

> **Code Definition Set**: Code Definition Sets>Dynamics Graduate Year Code

**Map Dynamics data to the contact facet**

- Navigate to this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Value Mapping Sets/xConnect Contact to Dynamics Contact Mappings/Contact Model to Dynamics Contact`
- Add the following item

> **Template** : Value Mapping
>
> **Item Name**: Graduate Year

- Set the following field values:

> **Source Accessor**: /sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/xConnect/xConnect Contact Custom Information Facet/Graduate Year on xConnect Graduate Year
>
> **Target Accessor**: Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/Dynamics/Dynamics Contact/GraduateYear on Dynamics Contact
>
> **Source Value Transformer**: Value Readers/Providers/Dynamics/Dynamics Graduate Year Description to Code Reader

**Facet interface and implementation**

- Create interface

```
public interface ICRMInfo : IFacet, IElement, IValidatable
    {
        string GraduateYear { get; set; }
    }
```

- Create class

```
[Serializable]
    public class CRMInfo: Facet, ICRMInfo, IFacet, IElement, IValidatable
    {
        private const string Year = "GraduateYear";
      
        public string GraduateYear
        {
            get
            {
                return base.GetAttribute<string>(Year);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetAttribute<string>(Year, value);
            }
        }
       
        public RYIInfo()
        {
            base.EnsureAttribute<string>(Year);
        }
 }
```

**Add custom facet to sitecore entities and model**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <model>
      <elements>
        <element interface="Namespace.IRYIInfo, AssemblyName" implementation="Namespace.RYIInfo, AssemblyName"/>
      </elements>
      <entities>
        <contact>
          <facets>
            <facet name="CRM" contract="Namespace.IRYIInfo, AssemblyName" />
          </facets>
        </contact>
      </entities>
    </model>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Troubleshooting**

1. Navigate to this location “/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/XXX/Pipelines/xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync Pipelines/Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline/Read Contacts from xConnect” and in “Contact Facets To Read” select custom facet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Swati, this worked like a charm.